# How to set a proximity alert(android) to a building in rectangular shape?

Tags: android, proximity, geofencing

I know that proximity alert can be set with in  a radius from a central latitude and longitude.But I want to know how to set a proximity alert for a particular building which is not in circular shape.

In my case I want to alert a user when he enters a building but not in the building vicinity.

Please post a link if you come across some useful stuff regarding this.

Any suggestion for solving my problem is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

set the radius a little more or a little less then the building size. however, take into account that the gps accuracy is somewhere around 20m, or even more